Redis/Redisson aquire lock twice
I faced with strange behavior in test, it looks like Redis lock is not barrier in all cases.
here is my lock method
fun blocking(runnable: Runnable, name: String, leaseTimeSec: Long = LEASE_TIME_SEC) {
    val lock = redissonClient.getLock(name)

    try {
       lock(name, lock, leaseTimeSec)
       runnable.run()
    } finally {
       unlock(name, lock)
    }
}

private fun lock(name: String, lock: RLock, ttl: Long) {
   lock.lock(ttl, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
   log.debug { "Locked: $name" }
}

and here is my test
    @RepeatedTest(100)
    fun `blocking call`() {
        val lockName = randomLock()

        var counter = 0L

        val repeatNumber: Long = 1000
        repeat((0..repeatNumber).count()) {
            Thread {
                service.blocking({
                    counter += 1
                }, lockName, -1)
            }.start()
        }

        Thread.sleep(100)
        counter shouldBeEqual (repeatNumber + 1)
    }

sometimes tests are failing, but 98-99% are successful.  What could be reason for that, I am using redis test-container, could it be a reason for that?
